# Matlab timer is not executed asynchronously

Tags: multithreading, matlab, user-interface, asynchronous

I am developing a Matlab UI program where the callback of a button pressed might take lots of time to process. So I basically want the callback to be executed asynchronously and ask the UI to update the callback result when it is ready.

Some [documents](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/explicit-multi-threading-in-matlab-part4) suggests doing this by using Matlab timer callback but I found the callback is still not executed asynchronously.

Here is a simple code for testing:

```
function [ ] = ThreadTest( )
    t = timer('StartDelay',0.1, 'TimerFcn',@utilityFcn);
    start(t);
    for i=1:10000;
        pause(0.1);
        fprintf('x');
    end
end

function utilityFcn(src,evt)
    % some lengthy calculation/update done here
    for i=1:100;
        temp = rand(1000,1000)*rand(1000,1000); 
    end
    fprintf('done');
end
```

I expect this program will continuously print 'x' in every 0.1 sec and there will be a print of 'done' when the callback is finished. However, in this example, the 'x' is only printed when the all lengthy computation is done (i.e., always printed after the 'done' is printed)

Comment: Execution of the timing callback is not done in parallel. This is explicitly stated in the UDM post you linked to: `So, while a timer callback executes, no other M-code can run.`

Comment: Hi @excaza I saw that and get confused by that as well. If so, what is the meaning to put timer in the callback? (if it will eventually hang the UI).